# filter results out of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure there's some sort of filter functionality built into javascript or jquery, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this using jquery `filter()`

Is there a way to filter all of the elements from a javascript object that have a particular value and get the object returned?

The functionality I'm after is like this, and though it isn't terribly long, I just wonder if there's something simpler.

Thanks!

```
(function(){
  var obj = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: false,
    d: true,
    e: true

  },
  f = [],
  true_obj = {};

  for (var i in obj){
    if (obj[i] === true){
      f.push(i);
    }
  }
  for (var c = 0; c < f.length; c++){
    true_obj[c] = f[c];
  }
  console.log(true_obj);

}());
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/alijek/1/)

Comment: It appears that the object is an array, yes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @JamesHill No, it's an object object. Posted the complete code from the jsbin. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using jQuery's built-in `map` method? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

```
(function(){
  var obj = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: false,
    d: true,
    e: true
  },
  f,
  true_obj = {};

  f = $.map(obj, function (val, key) {
      return (val === true) ? key : null;
  });
  for (var c = 0; c < f.length; c++){
    true_obj[c] = f[c];
  }
  console.log(true_obj);
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gVZVL/

The value evaluated in the `map` callback will be added to the resulting array if the value isn't `null`/`undefined`.

Also, if you're looking to copy the `f` array to `true_obj`, just use `slice` (instead of your `for` loop) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice :

```
true_obj = f.slice(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gVZVL/1/

**UPDATE:**

If you're just trying to filter items in an `Object`, try this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] !== true) {
        delete obj[key];
    }
}
```

And if you're trying to copy it (also keep the original `Object`), you could use:

```
var final_obj = {};
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === true) {
        final_obj[key] = obj[key];
    }
}
```

In either one of those, if you start with:

```
var obj = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: false,
    d: true,
    e: true
};
```

you will end up with

```
{
    a: true,
    b: true,
    d: true,
    e: true
}
```

(either overwritten or copied)

Comment: Seems to work. Not much shorter. I was just trying to get around creating an array, and then back to an object. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas Hmm maybe I misunderstood. So you have your `obj` Object. And you want to filter it based on `true` values. What do you want your final object to look like? An Object? Or Array?

Comment: Sorry. I'd like the final, filtered object to be an Object.

Comment: @thomas So you have `var first = {a: true, b: true, c: false};` and you want the final object to be `{a: true, b: true}`?

Comment: @thomas I just added some more stuff to my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Excellent. This is so straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas Awesome, no problem. Let me know if you need more clarification/help!

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterObject(object, predicate) {
  var result = {};
  for(var prop in object) {
    if(predicate(object[prop])) {
      result[prop] = object[prop];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
(function(){
  var obj = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: false,
    d: true,
    e: true

  };
  var true_obj = filterObject(obj, function(item) {
    return item === true;
  });
  console.log(true_obj);

}());
```

Comment: typo with the `var true_obj` also..this seems somewhat more complex than the original. thanks though.

Comment: Sorry about the type. It looks more complex because it loosely follows `filter` interface that you mentioned (instead of just hardcoded `=== true`).

Comment: Aha, can you show me an example of how you'd use it with something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you avoid extending the prototype. My solution is this:

I created a filter method to the obj object and It is using [HasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if the property is direct to the object or if it comes from the prototype chain.

```
(function(){
      var obj = {
        a: true,
        b: true,
        c: false,
        d: true,
        e: true
      },
     true_obj = {};

     obj.filter = function (value) {
        var result = [];

        for (var key in this) {
           if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             if (this[key] === value){
               result.push(key);  
              }
           }
        }

        return result;
     };

    var f = obj.filter(true);

    for (var c = 0; c < f.length; c++){
      true_obj[c] = f[c];
    }
    console.log(true_obj);

}());
```

Here is a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/alijek/2/edit)

Comment: This could turn into a religious debate, but there is nothing wrong with extending the prototype. If you want the in-built objects to do more than they do out of the box, extend them. It's a fundamental (and powerful) aspect of the language.

Comment: @OliverMoran The reason why it's not suggested to extend `Object`'s prototype is because it creates enumerable properties. And in your answer, you don't account for them. The way to make sure you're only enumerating real properties is with `hasOwnProperty`. So your `for` loop is incorrect. Also, a reason not to extend `Object` is because it's the parent-most class in the prototype chain, meaning all classes will inherit this method - `Array`, `String`, `Number`, etc.

Comment: Since ECMA5 is it possible to set properties to be not enumerable. I've updated my answer to include how. Leaving a method enumerable may cause problems in some code - but I would say it is better to avoid `for ... in` loops if you are not certain what properties are enumerable in an any given object. As for the `filter` method being inherited by `Array`, `String`, `Number`, etc. that was a design choice in my example. It may not be the correct design choice for every real-world implementation. The correct design decision will depend on more considerations than we are aware of here.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply extent the prototype of the `Object` object in JavaScript to include such a function.

I'm not sure exactly what kind of `filter` function you want, but here is an example:

```
Object.prototype.filter = function(val){
    for (var e in this) {
        if (this[e] === val) delete this[e];
    }
}

// Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "filter", { value:Object.prototype.filter, enumerable:false }); // this line will make the new method not enumerable, see discussion with Ian

// Example:
var obj = {a:"1", b:"2", c:"1"};
obj.filter("1");
alert(obj.a); // undefined
```